# Export a list from SharePoint 2010 into Visual Studio 2010

Tags: custom-list

How can I export a list from SP2010 and import it into my VS2010 for my feature? I used Imtech OCDExportList for SP2007 and it worked great for 2007, but doesn't appear to work for 2010. Is there any easy method of doing the same for SP2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Save site as template feature (not save list) that you find in site settings, then use the Import wsp template in VS2010 to import the list - just select the list and VS will determine what content types and fields are necessary to import too.